# 'a' tag with 'href' attribute inside 'p' tag

Tags: html

I'm using 'a' tag with 'href' inside the 'p' tag while working on my html layout.
This seems very common and logical. But according to HTML5.2 specification I can see that Content model for the 'p' tag is 'Phrasing content'.
[link to spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/grouping-content.html#grouping-content)!

At the same time the 'a' tag with 'href' attribute has the 'Categories:Interactive content' because it has a 'href' attribute.
  [I can see on the specification link](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/grouping-content.html#grouping-content)  "If the element has an href attribute: Interactive content."

So 'a' tag with 'href' is an Interactive content and we can not use it in 'p' tag as it allows inside only a 'Phrasing content'

My question is:
Is it possible to use 'a' with 'href' inside 'p' and is it according to HTML5 spec?

I have put my code spinet to validator and I have no warning or errors but I am confusing as HTML spec says that it is not allowed

```
<p class="footer__title">Write us 
  <a class="footer__link" href="mailto:osago-online@gmail.com">osago-online@gmail.com</a> 
</p>
```

Or code like this:

```
<p class="footer__text">
    Call us or search us in google
   <a class="footer__link" href="tel:0074732288507">+7 (473) 22-88-507</a>
   <a class="footer__link" href="https://www.google.com/">Search google</a>
</p>
```

I want to use links with 'href' inside 'p' tag and think that it is possible but HTML specification says NO from my point of view (for now I can see that the specification says yes from the Alohci's reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55668034/7655173)

Comment: Can you please paste the paragraph that says it's not allowed ?

Comment: No. I can't but I can see that Content model for the 'p' tag is **'Phrasing content' only**. At the same time 'a' tag with 'href' attribute has the 'Categories:Interactive content' As you can see 'Phrasing content' is not equal to 'Interactive content' Actually this is my the reason of my question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the document you linked, `p` tag can be followed by `address` tag and if you see the `address` tag specification [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/grouping-content.html#the-address-element) example 6 shows how to use `a` tag in `address` tag.

But in my opinion it is not a big deal if you use `a` tag in `p` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the example. It means that even  p end tag may be omitted and we can use link with href in p tag. But could you please show me how can I see it from specification. Where I can read it and how can I understand that  Interactive content is available in p tag. If only from this example than the specification is wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Interactive content and phrasing content are not mutually exclusive categories. `<a>` elements with an href attribute belong to both categories. You should read section [3.2.8.2. Kinds of content](https://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#kinds-of-content)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Alohci. It is much clearer now. So '<a>' with href is a Phrasing content and Interactive content.  But as I can see from the provided link some Interactive content belongs to  Phrasing content and some part of interactive content is outside phrasing content. How can I check if the interactive content is also phrasing or only interactive.

Comment: Only from the lists of elements. Only the details element is interactive content but not phrasing content.

Comment: So as I understand I should use 'logical and' instead of 'logical or' while reading the "Categories:" list in the specification. So if <a> element has the following categories in spec (Flow content.Phrasing content.If the element has an href attribute: Interactive content. Palpable content.) it means that <a> belongs to "Flow content" && "Phrasing content" &&"If the element has an href attribute: Interactive content"&&"Palpable content". It belongs to all listed contents at the same time? So I was wrong but not the specification)))))